# Any text analytics that are particularly useful/user friendly for literary analysis?

Tags: text-search, analytics

As a literature student I find being able to do stylistic analysis and macroanalysis to be useful, but it is arduous to have to individually count words in a large text. Looking for recommendations on programs others have found useful, while I am aware that pdf viewers and word processors can do word counts of particular words, I would be looking for something sophisticated enough to count word classes or even themes. I have looked at popular text mining software which seems catered for business and focused on sentimentality, which is inadequate for my needs. I have no knowledge of code of any kind so would need a program that is completely user friendly. While I have not found evidence that this kind of program even exists for a novice user, any recommendations would be appreciated.